# Ajax Paging in php

Tags: php, ajax

I just want the paging like the google adsense.
Means paging using the ajax..
How could i do this.?
Please send me reference if any
Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't understand what you're trying to do. Can you be more specific?

Comment: on first time page load get some search result on right side of the page, and then on click of next button, i want to load next results on same place with ajax..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called pagination.
The answer is somewhat long and have been covered in a lot of places.

I'd recommend you this one, which seems clean and detailed:

http://www.problogdesign.com/wordpress/how-to-ajax-post-pagination-in-mootools/

Googling for it should also give you more examples:

http://www.google.com/search?q=php+pagination+ajax

Hope that helps! :)

## Edit:

Try this one for PEAR:

http://www.alberton.info/pear_pager_tutorial_article_pagination.html

## Edit2:

Sorry, the first one is just pagination.

This other one for the AJAX version:

http://www.alberton.info/pear_pager_tutorial_javascript_navigation.html

Did it help?

Comment: i have gone through these links but its require lots of customization, i m using PEAR. will PEAR provide any class link this????

Comment: For simple paging currently i m using this code, but at this time i need to load next data without reloading the current page, that's why i have to use ajax for that.. Thanks....

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand the question, but gather you are trying to integrate ajax page loading into your PHP pages.

Take a look at [Xajax](http://xajaxproject.org/).

It is the quickest and easiest way in for a PHP dev, and you should be up in fifteen minutes.